# How to pin desktop to primary display with multiple monitor setup

Tags: xfce, multi-monitor, xrandr, desktop

I have a vertically placed external monitor while the primary monitor is laptop. Both of similar resolution. The vertical screen is not always connected, but only when I am in office.

The headache is that if I set the screen be the right of laptop, e.g.

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate right --right-of eDP-1
```

the desktop remains on laptop screen, it works fine except the inconvient fact that the vertically placed screen is on the physical left side of my laptop. 
If I set the external vertical screen to the left-of the laptop,

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate right --left-of eDP-1
```

the desktop bar together with the desktop will be placed on the left vertical screen, and due to the screen size difference the desktop bar will stick out from left screen into the right screen, privously opened windows will be part on left screen, part on right screen due to size difference.

How can I pin the desktop to laptop monitor eDP-1 or primary display 0?